# Лучшая программа для модификации http траффика на лету?

Tags: java, http

Недавно мне была поставлена лёгкая на первый взгляд задача.

Дано: JAR-приложение без исходников, которое падает при запуске с ошибкой из-за того что автор забросил проект.

Задача: Подменить один файл "на лету", который запрашивает софт из сети, и таким образом оживить ее.

Решение: Берем Fiddler,Charles и кормим ее недостающим файлом из моего сайта, при этом она обращается по адресу: `avtorpage.com/dl/update.lst`, а файл отдается с адреса `mypage.com/dl/update.lst`, но вся проблема в том, что общается она посредством Socket http соединения, из-за этого две вышеуказанных тулзы не видят ее.

Вопрос: Что же делать ? 
Декомпилировать не вариант, накрыто Зельдой и не хочу нарушать права разработчика.

Comment: К автору обращались?

Comment: Просто подменить ип-адрес `avtorpage.com` на адрес `mypage.com`. в файле `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` сделать запись `1.2.3.4       avtorpage.com` где вместо `1.2.3.4` написать ип-адрес `mypage.com`. При этом весь трафик для `avtorpage.com` пойдёт на `mypage.com`. Если требуется, то сервер `mypage.com` должен быть настроен на приём чужого доменного имени в запросах как родного.

Comment: Другой вариант - перенаправление средствами фаервёла. Как сделать - искать мануалы по `netsh`. Это может быть даже единственным способом, если окажется, что прога эта не пользуется dns, а в ней зашит определённый ип-шник.

Comment: Если подскажете как перенаправить именно ссылку, буду очень благодарен.